# Tri state checkboxes with jquery and bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am using the jquery bootstrap multiselect http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ . I was pretty happy with the plugin until a tricky requirement came. My multiselect is similar to the one as follows

```
        <select id="example4" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
```

My requirement is that I recieve a list of users where each user has preferences. ex: user1 likes cheese and tomatoes, user2 likes tomatoes, mushrooms and onions. so all the four options should be preselected when the dropdown is clicked. The tomatoes option should be checked and the other options should be checked in a intermediate state. I need something like this http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/ (which works awesome, by the way). I tried manipulating the checkbox through javascript by writing

```
             //leaving out the unnecessary code
              cb = $("#multiselectObj").find('input[value="'+objValue+'"]');
              $(cb).prop("indeterminate", true);
```

But the above code does not seem to have any effect. 
Can I even have any tri state in the select option ? Is there a way I can work around the issue or should I use a completely different plugin?? 
Any help from the experts is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by edit in the question. Converted to community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **Found the solution:** I got the next div from the current multiselect obj and got the checkbox. It works.

```
       function findDropdownCheckbox(ele, chkValue){
              divs = $(ele).next();
              cb = $(divs).find('input[value="'+chkValue+'"]');
              //console.log("divvvvvvvvvsss -");
              //console.log(cb);
              return cb;
       }
```